# Get a black/no image with asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'am posting an image from a console application to a asp.net web api. I'am getting a file in the folder but the image is black (no image). Do I have something wrong in my code?

```
public class UploadController : ApiController
{
    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public string Upload()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
        var filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"), request.Headers["filename"]);

        try
        {
            using (var fs = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
            {
                request.InputStream.CopyTo(fs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
        return "uploaded";
    }
}
```

**Edit**

My console app
http://pastebin.com/VsnDMYpb

Comment: Plz include your console application upload code

Comment: I would use `Request.Files` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. This works for me. I used this for multiple file upload

```
var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
{
    var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + postedFile.FileName);
    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
}
```

Comment: I don't get any image at all with this code. No errors. Do you have your "post code"?

Answer (score 0):

Use Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync

```
public Task<IQueryable<HDFile>> Post()
{
    try
    {
        var uploadFolderPath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/" + UploadFolder);
        log.Debug(uploadFolderPath);

        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            var streamProvider = new WithExtensionMultipartFormDataStreamProvider(uploadFolderPath);
            var task = Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith<IQueryable<HDFile>>(t =>
            {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
                }

                var fileInfo = streamProvider.FileData.Select(i =>
                {
                    var info = new FileInfo(i.LocalFileName);
                    return new HDFile(info.Name, Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri + "?filename=" + info.Name, (info.Length / 1024).ToString());
                });
                return fileInfo.AsQueryable();
            });

            return task;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable, "This request is not properly formatted"));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.Error(ex);
        throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message));
    }
}
```

The code I get from this [post](http://hintdesk.com/android-upload-files-to-asp-net-web-api-service/)